# Is "Select column from updated" available in "After Update" trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, triggers

Is "Select column from updated" available in "After Update" trigger? If not what other approach can be used. I want to update statistics in "TableB" based on updates done on "TableA".

Comment: Do you need a trigger and separate table? For tracking simple statistics, an indexed view may be appropriate (and means you can write less code)

Comment: Yes it is a necessary evil in my scenario. The rows in table A will have different status at different stages of time. I have to keep track of how many rows are in a particular status with each update in table. Also a row has to be counted twice if it's status is update to failure "Two times" on two different tries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Select column from inserted"
```

There is not an Update table. You have to use inserted instead. When you make an update, the old values are in the deleted table, and the new one are in the inserted table.

The update sentence are the only one that have data in inserted and deleted at the same time.